# Codeigniter get page number from url

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

Related thread: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34021534/ci-pagination-back-to-posts-link/34021929#34021929)

I have everything but one thing working in my pagination - I have a link "back to posts" which is supposed to take the user back to the last page they were viewing. For that I want to pass the page number used by CI to the view, but don't know how to do it. I want to pass the value to where the letter X is in the link.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url().'welcome/paginate/X'; ?>">Back to Posts</a>
```

Just to make things clear: Posts have "read more" link, which creates a view with a post's name, description etc. In it, the above link is also posted. I want to pass the page number of the page in which the post is.

Comment: You can do it using `URL segment`. Check this link for URL segment : https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html

Comment: great, it worked with rsegment; thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the uri segment 
Ex:

```
$this->uri->segment('3')
```